# ¿Cómo saber cual es la fecha mas grande de una consulta?

Tags: php, mysql, date

Buenas tardes tengo un sistema con php y mysql el cual saca los textos de un libro.
Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT
    tl.IdTexto,
    tl.tituloTexto,
    tl.IdEntregableTextoFinal,
    kec.Valor,
    DATE_FORMAT(ee.FechaPlaneadaFinal,'%Y-%m-%d') AS fecha,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF( DAY, '2020-06-09', DATE_FORMAT( ee.FechaPlaneadaFinal, '%Y-%m-%d' ) ) AS dias_trascurridos

FROM
    c_textosLibro AS tl 
    LEFT JOIN c_entregableEspecifico as ee on ee.IdEntregEspecifico=tl.IdEntregableTextoFinal
    LEFT JOIN k_entregableEspecifCheckList as kec on kec.IdEntregEspecif=ee.IdEntregEspecifico
WHERE
    tl.IdLibro = 63
```

el resultado es el siguiente.

[image: resultado de la consulta]

lo que busco hacer es comparar todos los resultados del campo fecha para poder sacar la más grande y esta tomarla como fecha general, tomando como ejemplo la imagen, la fecha general seria 2020-02-14

Comment: pero seria en una consulta aparte o en esa misma?

Answer (score 1):

Tendrias que agregar el ORDER BY col DESC. Te quedaria asi la consulta:

```
SELECT
    tl.IdTexto,
    tl.tituloTexto,
    tl.IdEntregableTextoFinal,
    kec.Valor,
    DATE_FORMAT(ee.FechaPlaneadaFinal,'%Y-%m-%d') AS fecha,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF( DAY, '2020-06-09', DATE_FORMAT( ee.FechaPlaneadaFinal, '%Y-%m-%d' ) ) AS dias_trascurridos

FROM
    c_textosLibro AS tl 
    LEFT JOIN c_entregableEspecifico as ee on ee.IdEntregEspecifico=tl.IdEntregableTextoFinal
    LEFT JOIN k_entregableEspecifCheckList as kec on kec.IdEntregEspecif=ee.IdEntregEspecifico
WHERE
    tl.IdLibro = 63
ORDER BY
    fecha DESC
```